How do I know when a live YouTube stream will start?
I'm using safari on iOS 16 looking at a youtube.com page for a live stream that allegedly has not started and is scheduled to start sometime in the future (since it's marked as upcoming in the UI). I'm logged in to my account.
The video player simply says:

Waiting for channel name
13 December 2024 19:02

Now I assumed that this would be the scheduled time for it to start, and that would've been great except that that was five hours ago.
At this point I usually assume wrong time zone settings, so I inspected general settings and noted that both location and language were set to Sweden and Swedish respectively, which is correct. I found no other regional settings whatsoever.
My OS already has the correct local time and time zone, and I did not find any disabled "experimental" Safari API pertaining to this in iOS settings.

Is the time stamp the scheduled starting time?
Which time zone is it in?
Are there time zone settings somewhere, that I did not find?

If time stamps aren't in my local time zone then I don't understand either a) who they're for, or b) why the time zone isn't explicit. As it currently stands I can't seem to make any use of the time stamp — not even to determine that "the live stream didn't start at the scheduled time", since other parts of the UI imply the opposite.

A tentative conclusion has to be that YouTube is showing me live streams that have actually already occurred hours ago as upcoming, and that this is a symptom of some inter-continental caching bug (delays this long in this context are probably best viewed as bugs). That would fit all observed behavior.
